# Unexpected behaviour when re-organising directory (python, shutil)

Tags: python, shutil

I have a function that reorganises a directory of locally saved data, but its behaving in an unexpected way. There are 3 folders, `current`, `previous` and `tma` (two months ago) and with the function below I am expecting that it will delete the existing `tma`, rename `current` -> `previous`, `previous` -> `tma` and then re-create and populate (with another function) a `current` folder.

```py
import os
import shutil

__PATH = os.getcwd()

def reorganise_directory():
    print(__PATH)
    destinations = ['current', 'previous', 'tma']
--->shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(__PATH, f'/data/{destinations[-1]}'))
    shutil.move(os.path.join(__PATH, f'/data/{destinations[1]}'), os.path.join(__PATH, f'/data/{destinations[-1]}'))
    shutil.move(os.path.join(__PATH, f'/data/{destinations[0]}'), os.path.join(__PATH, f'/data/{destinations[1]}'))
    return
```

This is the error I recieve:

[image]

It appears that for some reason, the `__PATH` variable, which prints out `C:\dev\python\smog_usage_stats` is being turned to just `C:\` in the line indicated by an arrow. I'm not sure why?

Comment: It looks like your mixing back slashes and forward slashes in your file paths. This error may be causing python to use the current root drive when creating the path because it can't resolve the full path name.

Comment: Ugh, yeah. I always forget the windows v linux backslash/frontslash discrepencies. Thanks!

Comment: No worries I go between the two as well. If you use the pathlib library for file paths it will auto convert your file paths to the correct os automatically so you can run your code on either machine with no changes. It can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use it:

```
import os
import shutil

__PATH = os.getcwd()

def reorganise_directory():
    print(__PATH)
    destinations = ['current', 'previous', 'tma']
    # Change f"/data/{destinations[x]}" to "data", destinations[x]
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(__PATH, "data", destinations[-1]))
    shutil.move(os.path.join(__PATH, "data", destinations[1]), os.path.join(__PATH, "data", destinations[-1]))
    shutil.move(os.path.join(__PATH, "data", destinations[0]), os.path.join(__PATH, "data", destinations[1]))
    return
```

Don't use Unix-like slashes on NT systems or backwards. It may cause unexpected behaviours + if you don't use slashes in 'os.path.join' (only names), you will have platform-indepedency, what would help to start your program, for example, on Linux or MacOS.